# Samsung Galaxy S2 Join contact Conflict

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I have joined my facebook, google, whatsapp and phone contacts. The problem starts when the display names are different.

Now the phone has its own mind which contact name to display. I tried un-joining them and leave the name i want to be displayed "in this case PHONE and join them back again.

This resolves the problem momentarily, but whenever I come back again, its the same.
This issue is also with Whatsapp, the contact name within wha

Can I choose which account's name is to be displayed by default?